# Create object with just value and an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Can i create javaScript object with just value `(without mentioning of property)` and an array of objects inside it?

Like below:

```
Car = {'12345', [{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}]}
```

I tried like this.
It works but i want to get rid of Id and Values from output

```
var Cars = {Id: '12345', Values:[{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}}]}
```

Comment: Please check out some documentation on Object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: What you actually want to create is an array. Afaik, objects are key-value data types; so what you want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: yes it can be done but not in pure JS, you need to modify your source. Honestly, JSON without property didn't make sense.

Comment: You can just create an array like this `var Cars = ['12345', {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}]` ... why do you want JSON without keys.

Comment: @simbada, maybe tell us why you want id without a key?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are key-value stores, so what you want to achieve is not possible.

But begs the question, why do you want to make the data an object? 
You can still work very effectively with arrays:

```
Car = ['12345', [{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}]]
```